# twitter-bootstrap buttons javascript doesnt work

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a control-group with a button group as checkboxes like this :

```
<div class="control-group" id="cyb3r" >
            <label class="control-label" for="c">C</label>
            <div class="btn-group navs controls" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
                <button class="btn" type="button">1</button>
                <button class="btn" type="button">2</button>
                <button class="btn" type="button">3</button>
            </div>

</div>
```

and I include these :

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="<?php echo base_url('assets/style/style.css');?>">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="<?php echo base_url('assets/style/bootstrap.min.css');?>">
<script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="<?php echo base_url('assets/script/jquery.js')?>"></script>
<script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="<?php echo base_url('assets/script/bootstrap.min.js')?>"></script>
<script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="<?php echo base_url('assets/script/bootstrap-button.js')?>">
    </script>
<script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="<?php echo base_url('assets/script/js.js')?>"></script>
```

and js.js :

```
$(function(){
    $('#cyb3r').button();  
});
```

I tried these also :

```
$(function(){
    $('.navs').button();  
});

$(function(){
    $('.control-group').button();  
});
```

but none of them work for that checkbox group.
but why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bootstrap.min.js` already includes `bootstrap-button.js`

you can remove

```
<script
type="text/javascript"
src="<?php echo base_url('assets/script/bootstrap-button.js')?>">
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that all libraries are included correctly?
Because for me it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/QchpT/

Comment: yes , I added a click event on navs class with an alert . that worked , and I checked also in headers , all are 200 OK

Comment: Have you been seen my example? I understood you correctly about what does not work? Button selection? Or what?

Comment: Yes I saw that , button selection doesn't work .
according to http://jsfiddle.net/QchpT/1/ , your example works without javascript too.
when u click on buttons they don't get actived - in my code -