# Bootstrap: Buttons not working

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, yii-booster

jQuery UI [Checkbox buttons](http://jqueryui.com/button/#checkbox) don't react on click, but radio buttons do.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
<a class="btn btn-primary" id="yw3">Left</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" id="yw4">Middle</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" id="yw5">Right</a>
</div>

<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
<a class="btn btn-primary" id="yw0">Left</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" id="yw1">Middle</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary active" id="yw2">Right</a>
</div>
```

I use the [YiiBooster](http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/) implementation of bootstrap which includes these javascripts:

```
jquery.js (jQuery JavaScript Library v1.8.3)
bootstrap.js (bootstrap-transition.js v2.3.2)
bootstrap.bootbox.min.js (bootbox.js v2.3.2)
bootstrap.notify.js (bootstrap-notify.js v1.0)
bootstrap-buttons.js (bootstrap-button.js v2.0.4)
```

Is there something missing?

Comment: What do you mean by they don't work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [twitter-bootstrap buttons javascript doesnt work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225010/twitter-bootstrap-buttons-javascript-doesnt-work)

Comment: why are you mixing v2.3.2 and v2.0.4 files ?

Comment: No idea why they were both included. Removed bootstrap-button.js and it works :)

Comment: sometimes if you include 2 of the same JS they will not work together.  Bootstrap.js contains alot of different js files combined into one.  Possibily this was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bootstrap.js` already includes `bootstrap-button.js`.

Remove `bootstrap-button.js` to fix this problem.

Thanks to [PW Kad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1200803/pw-kad) for the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225010/twitter-bootstrap-buttons-javascript-doesnt-work).