# yiibooster sortable table rows are not working

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, jquery-ui-sortable, yii-booster, yii-widgets

I have problem with a Yiibooster sortable table rows. It is not working because of two errors.

1. The file "http://yii-cms.com/protected/extensions/bootstrap/assets/js/jquery.sortable.gridview.js" is not found by the system (404), although the rest of yiibooster files are working and I did installation according to the instructions.
   The path to the "jquery.sortable.gridview.js" is generated by the system, I checked it and that file exists.

I installed Yiiboster by writing:

```
<?php
// main/config.php
Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', dirname(__FILE__).'/../extensions/bootstrap');
'preload'=>array('log', 'bootstrap'),
// autoloading model and component classes
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
    'application.modules.admin.components',
    'application.modules.admin.models.*',
    'bootstrap.*',
 ),
// application components
'bootstrap' => array(
     'class' => 'bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
 ),
?>
```

2. The second error occurs in view file, near the 'afterSortableUpdate' property.

   - `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Please give me some advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug of [YiiBooster](http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/), try it with the newest version or you may report it [here](https://github.com/clevertech/YiiBooster/issues/). Please mention your Yii version and YiiBooster version.

The assets need to be properly registered within Yii, so that they are cached in the *assets* folder. The *protected* folder is protected and requests to it are blocked.

Comment: thanks I already reported that issue to the link you suggested. By the way is it beneficial to use Yiistrap and Yiibooster together in one project?

Comment: Do not use two bootstrap extensions at the same time. The JavaScripts of the extension will overwrite each other with an incompatible bootstrap version or even block each other! Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225010/twitter-bootstrap-buttons-javascript-doesnt-work